# postgis spatial query assistance

Tags: indexing, postgis, spatial

Assuming I have three tables:

- A. Municipalities (MultiPolygon)
- B. Postcode centroids (Point)
- C. User data (Point)

Entries from (C) match entries on (B) with FK (code).

I am looking for an efficient way to:

> Count number of user data (C) in municipalities (A) using **ST_Contains**.

**BUT**

here is the catch:

> If an entry in C is NULL (or matches another condition) use if exists the matching entry in B using the FK !!!

Currently I have tried various patterns and although spatially querying A & B and A & C both are sub-second, once I add them all together in one query (goal) the outcome is over 4secs

Sample of what I've tried:

This is the worse (60+ secs):

```
SELECT
    A.*,
    (SELECT FROM 
        (SELECT CASE WHEN C.GEOM IS NULL THEN B.GEOM ELSE C.GEOM END
         FROM C LEFT JOIN B ON C.ID=B.ID) AS b 
         WHERE ST_CONTAINS(A.GEOM, b.GEOM)
    ) count
FROM
    A
```

This is 15 sec:

```
SELECT 
    A.ID, ..., -- other A fields
    COUNT(B.GEOM)
FROM
    A,
    (SELECT CASE WHEN C.GEOM IS NULL THEN B.GEOM ELSE C.GEOM END
     FROM C LEFT JOIN B ON C.ID=B.ID) AS b
WHERE
    ST_Contains(A.GEOM, b.GEOM)
GROUP BY
    A.ID, ... -- other A fields
```

As I said

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON ST_Contains(A.GEOM, B.GEOM)
```

and

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A LEFT JOIN C ON ST_Contains(A.GEOM, C.GEOM)
```

both return in under a second.

All indexes are in place for the foreign key as well (B.ID = C.ID)

Thanks

Comment: I should point out that the first query (60+ sec) outperforms the 2nd if the CASE statement is not needed (i.e. use only B points)

Answer (score 0):

Did you [make indexes](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-2.0/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#id2812160) for A.geom and B.geom?

It would be

```
CREATE INDEX idx_A ON A USING GIST ( GEOM );
VACUUM ANALYZE A (GEOM);
CREATE INDEX idx_B ON B USING GIST ( GEOM );
VACUUM ANALYZE B (GEOM);
```

Comment: Yes there are spatial indexes in place (forgot to mention)